# Algorithm.sty not found (TexMaker)

Tags: packages, texmaker, algorithms, ubuntu, linux

I have just downloaded texmaker to make a local copy of a tex file from overleaf but when I try to generate the pdf I get the following error

Latex Error: File 'algorithm.sty' not found.

My computer runs Ubuntu a fix online says to run the following command in the terminal

sudo apt-get install texlive-science

That hasn't worked either.

If anyone can help that would be much appreciated thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably there is just a typo. The quoted error message sais `algorthim` while, you propably wanted to use `algorithm`.

Comment: @leandriis: Is this a typo contest? :o)

Comment: You might want to install `apt-file`, then run `sudo apt-file update`  and then `apt-file search algorithm.sty`, this will tell you exactly which Ubuntu deb package provides this file (if any)

Comment: @leandriis The output was this, I will be honest I have no idea what to do with it.         latexml: /usr/share/perl5/LaTeXML/Package/algorithm.sty.ltxml
texlive-lang-arabic: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/simurgh/simurgh-algorithm.sty
texlive-science: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty

Comment: do not use the distro package manager; install texlive from https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: You might also try algorithms, algorithm2e and algorithmicx.

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same issue and installing texlive-science package solved the issue:

`sudo apt-get update -y`

`sudo apt-get install -y texlive-science`

Comment: thank you, this works for me too.

Comment: I have windows and I have the same problem. Texlive-science doesn't seem to exist for windows. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This certainly works, but on my machine, it indicates that upward of 100 MB will be used up in installing `texlive-science` It seems rather excessive. What is the point of everything else in `texlive-science` if you need only a few files from it(?) Is there a more parsimonious/cheaper way to install just the sty files that you need? See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74216080/bare-minimum-install-to-get-over-algorithm-sty-not-found-error as well.